# Variable Datetime Records and how to convert all into one format

Tags: python, datetime, convention

I have a list about 15000 rows long of Datetime strings all with different formats, i.e. some includes microseconds, some are missing dates, etc. I want to know if there is a parser that says:

Here is what should the there: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f

and if anything is missing, fill in

%Y <- 2014

%m <- 01

%d <- 01

...

I was just asked to give examples of the state of my data, so Ill give 5 lines of what some of this looks like

```
2014-7-15 6:35:13.000005
2014-7-10 6:35:15
2014-7-11 6:35
September-15, 6:35:13.000005
```

These are the varying kinds of formats. I understand that I need to parse differently for the 1st example vs. the 4th, however, given the 1st and the 2nd, or the 2nd and the 3rd, we'll say, is there a quick, If its missin .%f in %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f then set %f = 00000. Does that make sense?

Comment: Can you give more information on the state of your data? What does it look like if %Y is missing?

Comment: Here you go mfitzp, I expanded on what you asked. Thank you for commenting.

Comment: Here you go mfitzp, I expanded on what you asked. Thank you for commenting.

I have an idea that halfway works, but maybe there is something missing.

If I first split by space, then I split the first by hyphen (-) and the second by colon (:)... I can do it that way, but is there more of a standard way of handling it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) may be able to help you here. It accepts multiple text formats of dates, and returns a Python `datetime` object. For example, with your examples:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

>>> parse('2014-7-15 6:35:13.000005')
datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 15, 6, 35, 13, 5)

>>> parse('2014-7-10 6:35:15')
datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 10, 6, 35, 15)

>>> parse('2014-7-11 6:35')
datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 11, 6, 35)

>>> parse("September-15, 6:35:13.000005")
datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 15, 6, 35, 13, 5)
```

Once you have a `datetime` object you can freely output it in whatever format you like using `strftime()` with your preferred format string:

```
>>> parse('2014-7-11 6:35').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
'2014-07-11 06:35:00.000000'

>>> parse('September-15, 6:35:13.00000').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
'2015-09-15 06:35:13.000000'
```

The `python-dateutil` package is [available here on PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/) and can be installed with:

```
pip install python-dateutil
```